# Removing Specific Strings from File

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a python program that'll clean out my stylesheet of any unused classes. I want to remove the classes that aren't be used in the DOm from the stylesheet.

I managed to grab all the used classes from the DOM using the following code:

Right now I have it is so the found classes will be removed from the file so that I can see that it is working. I plan to switch it to keep the classes and remove all that are not part of the DOM as stated above.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

import requests
import cssutils
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

'''

Scrape the given website's html for all class and id use cases within the tags.
Append all classes and ids to a dictionary for later use cases.

Remove all items in stylesheet that aren't in the dictionary / being used in the html.

@author Francesco Hayes
@date May 24, 2019


TODO:
Maybe use the join method to concatenate the rules in between the styles.

'''

WEB_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/website/index.html'

def get_page_classes(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    return [value for element in soup.find_all(class_=True) for value in element["class"]]


def get_file_classes(file):
    with open(file) as fp:
        return fp.read()


def convert_classes(classes, file_classes):
    new_lines = []    
    new_classes = []

    # loop over existing lines, do your changes, and build up a list of new_line

    for i in range(len(classes)):
        classes[i] = '.' + classes[i]
        new_classes.append(classes[i])
        print(new_classes)


    i = 0
    while i < len(file_classes):

        if file_classes[i] in new_classes:
            new_lines.append(file_classes[i])
            i += 1

            while file_classes[i][0] != '.':
                print(file_classes[i])
                new_lines.append(file_classes[i])
                i += 1

        else:
            i += 1


    return new_lines


def write_lines(file, lines):
    with open(file, 'w') as fp:
        for line in lines:
            fp.writelines(line)


page_classes = get_page_classes(WEB_URL)
print('Classes from Website: ', page_classes)

file_classes = get_file_classes("./website/style.css")
file_classes = file_classes.split()
print('\nClasses from Stylesheet: ', file_classes)

new_lines = convert_classes(page_classes, file_classes)
print('\nThe new stylesheet: ', new_lines)

write_lines("test.css", new_lines)
```

I have tried looping through it as a list and splitting the classes by their indicator: "."; however, I then run into the issue of having to rewrite the new filtered styles into a file. Each class will need the '.' again.

Essentially, I am trying to automate a process that'll save me time from doing it manually.

I hope this makes sense and if not I can try explaining again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to build a new list of lines, and then write that to the file.

Note that while testing particularly, it's best to write to a different file.

It's also good practice to make your functions return things, which you then chain together elsewhere. This keeps your code clean, and makes functions easier to read, easier to debug as well as reusable.

It's unclear to me exactly what you're doing by reading classes from the DOM as well as a file, so I'll summarise here

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_page_classes(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    return [value for element in soup.find_all(class_=True) for value in element["class"]]

def get_file_classes(file):
    with open(file) as fp:
        return fp.readlines()

def convert_classes(classes, file_classes):
    new_lines = []
    # here you should loop over the lines, do your changes, and build up a list of new_line
    # for line in file_classes:
    #   . .. whatever... 
    #    new_lines.append(...) 
    return new_lines

def write_lines(file, lines):
    with open(target_file, 'w') as fp:
        for line in lines:
            fp.writeline(line)

page_classes = get_page_classes(WEB_URL)
file_classes = get_file_classes("./website/bootstrap.css")
new_lines = convert_classes(page_classes, file_classes)
write_lines("output.css", new_lines)
```

The nice thing about breaking it into functions is that you can print say, page_classes, and comment out the lines after, just to see what you're getting back from each function. Note that the write_lines function doesn't really need to return anything.

Comment: I see what you're doing but the problem that I am still encountering is looping over the existing lines from the stylesheet and making those changes for the new file. The get_file_classes reads the file odd and not by line.

Comment: The get_file_classes() returns a list of lines, which you can then loop over in convert_classes, which is what I meant by the comment in that function. Edited answer.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my code snippet above but I am still struggling to get it to work.